# What is the fastest method to find the largest Fibonacci-Number that fits in an int?

Tags: c++, algorithm, numeric

I admit the question is a bit academic. However, I believe that the solution is showing some insight in (C++) numerics.

Note that the Nth Fibonacci-Number can be calculated recursively with

```
int Fibonacci(int N)
{
    if (N==1 || N==2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return Fibonacci(N-1) + Fibonacci(N-2);
}
```

For this question the above brute force method is not the answer. This is because the
Nth Fibonacci-Number can be calculated non-recursively with:

```
long int Fibonacci(int N)
{
    double num1 = pow((1+sqrt(5))/2.0,N);
    double num2 = pow((1-sqrt(5))/2.0,N);

    return (num1-num2)/sqrt(5);
}
```

Comment: The fastest method is to pre-calculate the answer, and then hard-code it into the code (preferably assigned to a constant rather than as a magic number).

Comment: @Eljay: Yes, "I admit the question is a bit academic".

Comment: Not just academic, I do that quite often.  I make a little program (in Python or C++) that outputs pre-calculated data that I embed in my C++ code.  It's a good technique to have in your toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1 (not the fastest):

Using the non-recursiv method to calculate the Nth Fibonacci-Number
one can find the largest Fibonacci-Number that fits in an int with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <chrono>

long int Fibonacci(int n)
{
    double num1 = pow((1+sqrt(5))/2.0,n);
    double num2 = pow((1-sqrt(5))/2.0,n);

    return (num1-num2)/sqrt(5);
}
 
int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    int IndexMax = 1;
    while (Fibonacci(IndexMax)<INT_MAX) 
    {
        ++IndexMax;
    }
    --IndexMax;
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
    
    std::cout << "IndexMax = " << IndexMax << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Fibonacci_two(IndexMax): " << Fibonacci(IndexMax) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "calculation time: " << elapsed.count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

You can [run the code for method 1 online](https://godbolt.org/z/6TB9Wf) to see the following output:

```
IndexMax = 46
Fibonacci_two(IndexMax): 1836311903
calculation time: 33 microseconds
```

But there is an even faster method:

## Method 2:

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Identification) it is possible to invert the explicit formula for the Nth Fibonacci-Number. With this trick we can implement an even faster method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <chrono>

long int Fibonacci(int n)
{
    double num1 = pow((1+sqrt(5))/2.0,n);
    double num2 = pow((1-sqrt(5))/2.0,n);

    return (num1-num2)/sqrt(5);
}

double Fibonacci_invert(double Fn)
{
    double num1 = Fn*sqrt(5.0);
    double num2 = sqrt(5.0*Fn*Fn+4.0);
    double phi = (1.0 + sqrt(5.0))/2.0;

    return round(log((num1+num2)/2.0)/log(phi));
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    int IndexMax = Fibonacci_invert(INT_MAX);
    int FibonacciMax = Fibonacci(IndexMax);

    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
    
    std::cout << "IndexMax: " << IndexMax << std::endl;
    std::cout << "FibonacciMax: " << FibonacciMax << std::endl;
    std::cout << "calculation time: " << elapsed.count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks to [Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil) it is to note that `Fibonacci_Invert` is not generally a correct function for finding the largest Fibonacci number not larger than its argument.

You can [run the code for method 2 online](https://godbolt.org/z/uHDVEr) to see the following output:

```
IndexMax: 46
FibonacciMax: 1836311903
calculation time: 23 microseconds
```

Comment: It should be noted that `Fibonacci_invert` may work for values like `INT_MAX` that are the maximum values of various integer types within a reasonable range, but it is not generally a correct function for finding the largest Fibonacci number not larger than its argument. This is because there are rounding errors in converting its argument to its parameter and in nearly every operation inside it. Compiled with Apple Clang 11.0.0 and executed on macOS 10.14.6, it produces index 5 for input 8, corresponding to Fibonacci number 5. Similarly, it is one too low for 144, 377, 2584, 46368, and more.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: I fixed the code. The issue was a missing `round` in the function `Fibonacci_invert`

Comment: Trying to fix floating-point errors by blunt rounding is not generally a good idea. In this case, it breaks the routine for Fibonacci numbers 2 (produces index 4, for Fibonacci number 3) and 3 (produces 5, for 5). As I noted, the routine worked for integer-type-maximums within a reasonable range. That is what the question asked for, so it suffices. It should just be noted that it does not work generally for other values. Crafting a complete solution for all integers might not be worthwhile.

Comment: Within range, I might expected `Fibonacci_invert` to be off by at most one, within bounds depending on the floating-point type used. So testing its initial answer by using `Fibonacci` to get the corresponding number and compare it to the input of `Fibonacci_invert` might suffice to correct, within bounds.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: Thank you very much for your comments! I added a appropriate note to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I copied your first example and dropped in a function I've used many times. It uses data instead of instructions and a simple lookup instead of calculation. It has a hardcoded table of fibonacci values that fit into an 64-bit integer. Of course, the table could be made smaller if only 32-bit values are needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <chrono>

long int Fibonacci(int n)
{
    static const long int seq[] = {
        0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610,
        987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025,
        121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309,
        3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169,
        63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733,
        1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073, 4807526976, 7778742049,
        12586269025, 20365011074, 32951280099, 53316291173, 86267571272,
        139583862445, 225851433717, 365435296162, 591286729879,
        956722026041, 1548008755920, 2504730781961, 4052739537881,
        6557470319842, 10610209857723, 17167680177565, 27777890035288,
        44945570212853, 72723460248141, 117669030460994,
        190392490709135, 308061521170129, 498454011879264,
        806515533049393, 1304969544928657, 2111485077978050,
        3416454622906707, 5527939700884757, 8944394323791464,
        14472334024676221, 23416728348467685, 37889062373143906,
        61305790721611591, 99194853094755497, 160500643816367088,
        259695496911122585, 420196140727489673, 679891637638612258,
        1100087778366101931, 1779979416004714189, 2880067194370816120,
        4660046610375530309, 7540113804746346429
    };
    return n < int(sizeof seq / sizeof seq[0]) ? seq[n] : -1;
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    int IndexMax = 1;
    while (Fibonacci(IndexMax)<INT_MAX) 
    {
        ++IndexMax;
    }
    --IndexMax;
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);

    std::cout << "IndexMax = " << IndexMax << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Fibonacci_two(IndexMax): " << Fibonacci(IndexMax) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "calculation time: " << elapsed.count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

This is the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/RCruMe) output:

```
IndexMax = 46

Fibonacci_two(IndexMax): 1836311903

calculation time: 0 microseconds
```

It's considerably faster and I hope it doesn't violate the spirit of the question. It doesn't show numeric insights but does illustrate the useful technique of a code vs data tradeoff.